# How to get application instance from anywhere in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

I do not create Application object explicitly and suppose Vaadin does it silently.

How can I get a reference to it?

Answer (score 3):

In Vaadin 7 is called UI.
Accessible with:

```
UI.getCurrent();
```

And for your own methods in extended UI like:

```
((MyUI) UI.getCurrent()).getMyData();
```

More info in [Vaadin book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.global.html).